# ServiceStack - Use Ninject instead of Funq

Tags: ninject, servicestack

I am trying to use ServiceStack with Ninject rather than Funq. I have the following:

```
public interface IContainerAdapter
{
    T Resolve<T>();
    T TryResolve<T>();
}

public class NinjectIocAdapter : IContainerAdapter
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectIocAdapter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return this.kernel.Get<T>();
    }

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        return this.kernel.TryGet<T>();
    }
}
```

Then inside my Configure method:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
    ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    container.Adapter = new NinjectIocAdapter(kernel);

    //Set MVC to use the same Funq IOC as ServiceStack
    //ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
}
```

But I get the following error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'NinjectIocAdapter' to 'ServiceStack.Configuration.IContainerAdapter'.`

I'm also unsure whether I have to uncomment the line to set  MVC to use Funq IoC? I have commented it out as I will be using Ninject. Is that correct?

I assume once this is all working. I can simply register any dependencies inside:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code exactly matches [the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) with one subtle difference.

You have to use `ServiceStack.Configuration.IContainerAdapter` instead of your own `IContainerAdapter`
.

Delete your implementation, add a reference to `ServiceStack.Configuration` and you should be fine.